# GlobalKTable as QueryableStore with Kafka Streams Binder

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I'm using `spring-boot-starter-parent` version `3.1.2` and `spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams` version `4.0.3`

The vast majority of examples online show creating a GlobalKTable with the `@Input` annotation, which has been deprecated. I have yet to find a working example of how to create a GKT as a KeyValueStore with the latest version of Kafka Streams Binder.

The closest I've found is to bypass Binder and manually create a KafkaStreams bean with the GKT:

```java
@Bean
public KafkaStreams kafkaStreams(
    @Value("${spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.brokers}") String brokers) {
  StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();

  // Create a GlobalKTable
  builder.globalTable(
      Topics.GKT_TOPIC,
      Materialized.<Key, Value, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as(
              Stores.MY_GKT_STORE_NAME)
          .withKeySerde(KeySerde)
          .withValueSerde(ValueSerde));

  // Setup stream processing logic here...

  Properties config = new Properties();
  config.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "my-app-id");
  config.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, brokers);
  KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), config);

  // Start the streams
  streams.start();

  return streams;
}
```

Could anyone point me to Docs or an example of how to do this with the latest version of Kafka Streams Binder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out how to do this in [the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#_using_customizer_to_register_a_global_state_store)

> As mentioned above, the binder does not provide a first class way to register global state stores as a feature. For that, you need to use the customizer. Here is how that can be done.

```java
@Bean
public StreamsBuilderFactoryBeanCustomizer customizer() {
    return fb -> {
        try {
            final StreamsBuilder streamsBuilder = fb.getObject();
            streamsBuilder.addGlobalStore(...);
        }
        catch (Exception e) { }
    };
}
```