# Kafka Streams Binder: Accessing a Global State Store

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

Related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77019792/globalktable-as-queryablestore-with-kafka-streams-binder):
I'm using `spring-boot-starter-parent` version `3.1.2` and `spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams` version `4.0.3`

I've created a GlobalKTable in with the following code:

```java
@Bean
public StreamsBuilderFactoryBeanCustomizer customizer() {
    return fb -> {
        try {
            final StreamsBuilder streamsBuilder = fb.getObject();
            streamsBuilder.addGlobalStore(...);
        }
        catch (Exception e) { ... }
    };
}
```

However I need to access this GKT from a scheduled task (outside of my binder stream functions). Trying to access the store with the InteractiveQueryService throws an `UnknownStateStoreException`.

The only way I've found to do this is to manually register the KafkaStream object as a Bean :

```java
@Bean
public StreamsBuilderFactoryBeanCustomizer customizer(
    GenericApplicationContext applicationContext) {

    return fb -> {
        try {
            final StreamsBuilder streamsBuilder = fb.getObject();
            streamsBuilder.addGlobalStore(...);
            applicationContext.registerBean(
                MY_BEAN_NAME, KafkaStreams.class, fb::getKafkaStreams);
        }
        catch (Exception e) { ... }
    };
}
```

And then later in my Scheduled task retrieve the KafkaStreams Bean from the ApplicationContext

```java
@Scheduled
public void myTask() {
  var ks = ((KafkaStreams) applicationContext.getBean(MY_BEAN_NAME));
    var myGKT =
        ks.store(
            StoreQueryParameters.fromNameAndType(
                MY_STORE_NAME, QueryableStoreTypes.keyValueStore()));
```

This seems very round-about. How are you intended to access a GKT in the latest version of Kafka Streams Binder?

Answer (score -1):

Accessing a **GlobalKTable** or any state store created within a Kafka Streams topology from outside (like in a scheduled task) usually involves the **InteractiveQueryService**. This service provides a means to query state stores directly without needing to go through Kafka.

The **UnknownStateStoreException** you're encountering usually happens because the state store is either not yet ready, or Kafka Streams doesn't know about it yet. This could be due to several reasons:

1. **Name mismatch**: Ensure that the name you use with **InteractiveQueryService** or **KafkaStreams.store(...)** is the exact name of your store.
2. **Your application is not yet running**: Ensure that your streams application is in a **RUNNING** state. Before reaching this state, the store may not be query-able.
3. **Not all instances have the global store**: **GlobalKTable** (or any global store) is, as the name implies, global. That means all instances of your service should have a full copy of it. Ensure that all instances have loaded and processed the store.

I understand you are looking for a more streamlined approach. for better experience follow these steps:

1. **State Stores are ready**: You can listen for the **StreamsBuilderFactoryBean** to ensure the state stores are ready.

```
@Autowired
private InteractiveQueryService interactiveQueryService;

@Scheduled
public void myTask() {
    try {
        ReadOnlyKeyValueStore<String, MyValue> store = 
            interactiveQueryService.getQueryableStore(MY_STORE_NAME, QueryableStoreTypes.keyValueStore());

        // ... Use the store to fetch values.
    } catch (UnknownStateStoreException e) {
        // Handle or log the exception. You can retry after a delay.
    }
}
```

2. **Add StreamListener lifecycle hooks**: You can use the **@StreamListener** lifecycle hooks to know when your streams are ready.

```
@StreamListener(target = Processor.INPUT, condition = "headers['type']=='...'")
public void input(...) {
    // Your logic ...
}

@StreamListener("process-0")  // This assumes your input channel name is process-0
public void onEvent(...) {
    // Once this is called, it means your Kafka Streams instance is running and the state stores should be available.
}
```

3. **Configuration**: Ensure that you have **spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.application.server** defined. This is needed for **InteractiveQueryService**.

With these steps, you should be able to access your **GlobalKTable** with **InteractiveQueryService** without having to directly deal with the **KafkaStreams** object or the **ApplicationContext**. Remember to always handle the **UnknownStateStoreException** exception as the store might not always be immediately available.